# Long term single entry tourist visa for Dubai: using this can I work in company?

Tags: visas, dubai, work

As company given me this visa and they said that you can work with this and I asked him in that period they will give me salary or not?

They said we given offer letter so we'll give you salary.
And in the sponsor name there is no name of company, it's some holiday party name mentioned.

Please let me know this is right or wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you employed outside Dubai and visiting there for a short time as part of your employment (for example, you're a software engineer living and working in some other country and you'll be visiting Dubai for a couple of weeks to install your company's software on a client's computers) or are you moving long-term to work for a company based in Dubai? The answer may well be different. Having said that, the sponsor name not matching is a huge worry.

Answer (score 9):

We'd have to see the visa to be sure (if you want to post a picture of it with your personal information blacked out, that would be helpful), but this sets off a lot of alarm bells.

A tourist visa is for tourism. If you work while on a tourist visa, you are working illegally and there could be serious consequences for both you and the employer. Assuming that what you have is a tourist visa, you should not try to use it to work.

In addition, an employer willing to break the law in this way may intend to break the law in other ways, such as not paying your salary or mistreating you.

Comment: If you start working on a tourist visa you are open to all sort of threats from your company or others, such as "work for half what we promised or we will tell the authorities you are working illegally".

Comment: You should also consider contacting the UAE authorities. As of right now you have done nothing wrong, and if you can point to this company as giving you an invalid visa to work with, the authorities would be interested to know.

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot work on a visit visa. It is illegal. In fact, you should report this situation to the nearest UAE embassy as there is a high chance this employer is also violating the labor law by trying to skirt the visa process.

If you do attempt to enter the country, there is a good chance you will be denied and then deported.

There are also other things wrong with this situation:

1. An offer letter is not a contract of employment. The contract is a legal document, based on which you have certain rights, and is registered with the UAE government.
2. The fact that the company is not mentioned as a sponsor tells you that the job opportunity is not genuine.
3. Normally with companies like this, the offer letter states a very high salary, and if you manage to enter the country you are put on a different salary (usually paid in cash) and the job you are doing is not what is mentioned in the offer letter.  You also are not given benefits you are entitled to by law (like mandated days off, tickets to your home country, insurance, etc.) because you are an illegal worker.

**Do not accept this offer**

As far as the visa situation, in UAE, there are multiple kinds of short visit visas:

1. Transit visas, valid for 72 hours.
2. On-arrival visas, valid for 30 days; available for certain nationalities only.
3. Electronic visas, you have to apply before you enter the country. 30 days, available for residents of the GCC and some others.
4. Tourism visas. Available for 30, 60, 90 days; and some available with multiple entry.

None of these visas allow you to work. It states so directly on the visa form.